# MacOS Time Machine extremely slow

Tags: macos, time-machine, macos-mojave

I have a Macbook Pro Middle 2012 running Mojave 10.14.4 with SSD 250Gb internal drive. I bought a external SSD 250Gb Seagate Barracuda drive to make backup with Time Machine software, but for my surprise my backup is extremely slow. For an idea, in 12 hours, only 120Mb was backed up.

May anyone help me?

Comment: How did you connect the external drive to the Mac? If USB, does it show up as a 5Gbps USB 3.0 device when you do a system report?

Comment: I use Carbon Copy and the backup has done in 40 minutes. Thanks.